# Can not start microservices in IntelliJ cause of h2 web console

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster, h2

I have a microservice architecture. Everything works fine when I start it right from the console via maven.

However, when I use IntelliJ and want to launch the gateway application, IntelliJ creates the H2 Database inside the root directory instead of inside my gateways application.

The problem is that this H2 Webconsole is running on port 8082. However, this port is actually used by another microservice (orderManagement) and is therefore blocked.

I can't see any error inside my h2.server.properties of the gateway application. (See picture, opened file)

I created the everything with JHipster.

Does anyone know

1. Which files Intellij creates exactly?
   At least according to this thread it is the H2 database itself. I had never seen the files before.
2. Where does IntelliJ get the settings for port 8082?

[image]
[image]

Comment: As for the directory for the database, try to change the working directory in the IDE's Run Configuration. As for port - it is needed to know how do you initialize the service.

Comment: I never had such problem in IntelliJ but I run Spring Boot apps using their main classes. H2 console does not open a specific port, it's just a servlet that uses the web port of its embedding app. JHipster opens a TCP for external access to H2 in DatabaseConfiguration.java but it's a higher number so it's unrelated.